# Variables declared by &&

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Thinking about (x|r|l|pr|gl)values, the following question came to my mind:

Consider the following two variable declarations:

```
X x = ...;
```

and

```
X&& x = ...;
```

and assume the `...` do *not* deliver an xvalue.

Can anybody think of code *not* using `decltype` in which this makes a difference? In both cases, `(x)` will by an lvalue of type `X`, won't it?

Comment: I mean the difference in the using the variables so declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template non-type arguments [cannot refer to a temporary](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1). Thus, given

```
struct X {};
X purr() { return {}; }

X x1 = purr();
X&& x2 = purr();

template<X&> class woof {};
```

we have

```
woof<x1> w1; // OK
woof<x2> w2; // Error
```

---

If `...` isn't limited to a prvalue of type `X`, then slicing is a less obscure way to make the two non-equivalent. Given:

```
struct X { virtual ~X() = default; };
struct Y : X {};

Y meow() { return {}; }
```

Then:

```
X x1 = meow();        // slices
X&& x2 = meow();      // doesn't slice
```

Thus:

```
dynamic_cast<Y&>(x1); // throws std::bad_cast
dynamic_cast<Y&>(x2); // OK
```

Comment: That's very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe artificial example, but with

```
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X operator =(const X&) = delete;
    X(X&&) = delete;
    X operator =(X&&) = delete;
};

X makeX() {return {};}
```

following compiles

```
X&& x = makeX();
```

whereas following doesn't

```
X x = makeX();
```

Comment: `const` reference would work too, if you do not mind constness.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the comments. I was not aware of that, so I learned something. My question, however, targeted more the code using the variable.

Comment: Comment: That's kind-of odd. The && seem to suggest that `x` is something you should move from, yet your example works by the mere fact that you *cannot* move `X`s.